Is it possible to use a C like array in C#?
I want to create a class that is basically just a fixed size array with some functions to it.
This would be done like this:
private class SomeClass : SomeSuperClass {
    private readonly SomeType[] children = new SomeType[256];
    ...
}

Now this would work logically. But I think this will make the array a seperate heap object, which I do not want.
I would much rather let it behave, as if I would be doing the following in C++:
class SomeClass : SomeSuperClass {
    SomeType children[256];
    ...
}

Is there any way of doing this in C# or do I have to rely on my compiler to know to optimize this?
It is not a big problem, but it does bother me and I could not find anything about this on my own.

Sounds like premature optimization to me

See inline arrays.

@EtiennedeMartel thank you, this is what I was looking for. When searching for literally "C# inline array" I could only find things about Syntax.

Note that if you declare an inline array struct and then put that struct in a class, when you create an instance of that class the inline array is still going to be placed on the heap. It has to be "structs all the way down" to ensure everything is on the stack.

@MatthewWatson my understanding is that the OP would like only to avoid the additional heap allocation for the array inside the class ("But I think this will make the array a seperate heap object, which I do not want.").

As @EtiennedeMartel commented, you can use an inline array for this:

Inline arrays are used by the runtime team and other library authors
to improve performance in your apps. Inline arrays enable a developer
to create an array of fixed size in a struct type. A struct with an
inline buffer should provide performance characteristics similar to an
unsafe fixed size buffer.

An example in your case:
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(256)]
public struct ChildrenArray
{
    private SomeType _element0;
}

private class SomeClass : SomeSuperClass {
    private readonly ChildrenArray children = new ChildrenArray();
    //...
}

children[i] will give you access to the ith element, just like with a normal array.
Note: it is available since C# 12.

There is no way to do this without an unsafe buffer before C# 12, is that right?

Not as far as I know.

Before C# 12, you can use fixed size buffers, but they require unsafe code. In particular, you must use pointers to access the buffer's elements. An inline array type implicitly converts to a span, so they're inherently easier to use (and don't need unsafe).
